# how to skip commas to read information in c++

Tags: c++

This is an assignment and I am stuck in the first information reading process..
I need to read information from a file "bank.txt".
Every line of the file is like this:
rice(China),13,2016-8-3,5kg

I have wrote a cpp for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Food
{
    string name;
    int quantity;
    string expireDate;
    string unit;
    bool selected;
};

void all(Food item[]);

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    Food bank[100];
    infile.open("bank.txt");

    string text, temp[400];
    string dummy;
    int num;
    stringstream linestream;

    while(infile.good())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                getline(infile, text, ',');
                temp[4 * i + j] = text;
            }

            istringstream(temp[4 * i + 1]) >> num;
            bank[i].name = temp[4 * i];
            bank[i].quantity = num;
            bank[i].expireDate = temp[4 * i + 2];
            bank[i].unit = temp[4 * i + 3];
        }
    }

    all(bank);
    return 0;
}

void all(Food item[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << item[i].name << ".." << item[i].quantity << ".." << item[i].expireDate << ".." << item[i].unit << endl;
}
```

But this runs into some problems and the lines of odd numbers only displayed name.

How can I modify my code to make it behave normally??

Comment: What is the contents of `bank.txt`? What should exactly be the output? What output do you get?

Comment: Please enlighten us with the content of your bank.txt, at least fake data with the same format.

Comment: @AntonSavin @Raistmaj He said the content is `rice(China),13,2016-8-3,5kg` every line. right?

Comment: right the content is rice(China),13,2016-8-3,5kg every line. This program is only to check i have extracted the right information

Comment: [`while(infile.good())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `','` as `getline`'s separator leaves newlines in the stream.

Instead, first read a whole line, then use a `stringstream` built from that to extract the parts.
(For some reason, you have declared a variable that seems to be for this, but you never use it.)

```
string line;
if (getline(infile, line))
{
    istringstream linestream(line);
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        getline(linestream,text,',');
        temp[4*i+j]=text;
    }
    //...
```

There's also the problem of `while (infile.good())`, which you shouldn't do - you probably need to restructure your code.
Read more about it in [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) (it's about `eof`, but the same principle about "good" and "bad" streams hold here).

Answer (score 0):

You should also take into account the new line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Food
{
    string name;
    int quantity;
    string expireDate;
    string unit;
    bool selected;
};

void all(Food item[], int count);

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    Food bank[100];
    infile.open("bank.txt");


    string text, temp[400];
    string dummy;
    int num;
    stringstream linestream;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        getline(infile, text, ',');
        if (!infile.good()) {
            break;
        }
        temp[4 * i] = text;
        for (int j = 1; j<3; j++)
        {
            getline(infile, text, ',');
            temp[4 * i + j] = text;
        }
        getline(infile, text, '\n');
        temp[4 * i + 3] = text;

        istringstream(temp[4 * i + 1]) >> num;
        bank[i].name = temp[4 * i];
        bank[i].quantity = num;
        bank[i].expireDate = temp[4 * i + 2];
        bank[i].unit = temp[4 * i + 3];
        i++;
    }

    all(bank, i);
    return 0;
}

void all(Food item[], int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
        cout << item[i].name << ".." << item[i].quantity << ".." << item[i].expireDate << ".." << item[i].unit << endl;
}
```

Comment: the information are displayed properly, thx.  but there are many lines of "340g..340..340g..340g"  after that. don't know why..